# how to select images with JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two Images here and I want to show larger when Image clicked but it's only increase size of **Image1** because of **document.image[0]** but how to create this for multiple image.

**Note :** I did this using **document.getElementById('#').style.width;** and it's works but is it possible to do this using **document.images**?

```js
function iw(){

   
    var num = document.images[0].style.width;
  if (num == '300px') {
      document.images[0].style.width='500px'
    
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<img src="https://cdn-prod.medicalnewstoday.com/content/images/articles/325/325466/man-walking-dog.jpg" style="width:300px;"  onclick="iw()">
<img src="https://cdn-prod.medicalnewstoday.com/content/images/articles/325/325466/man-walking-dog.jpg" style="width:300px;"  onclick="iw()">


</body>
</html>
```

**Thank You to help me !**

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use `document.images` over the alternatives?

Comment: The name of the property says it all: `document.images`, _image**s**_, plural. That is, all the _images_ of the document. Why would _all images_ have _one singular_ style? The answer below gives the subtle hint to do `console.log(document.images);` which is part of basic debugging that you should’ve done before.

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead. Familiarize yourself with the [DOM API](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and with [events](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/Events).

Comment: yes, I want to select all the images.

Comment: Use [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple event listeners — it’s more maintainable, and applies to dynamically added elements. E.g., use an [event argument](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Event/target). See [the tag info](/tags/event-delegation/info) and [What is DOM Event delegation?](/q/1687296/4642212).

Comment: Another thing is that `if(num=='300px')` is very fragile. Checking CSS properties directly is [best avoided](/q/55071684/4642212). Instead, a CSS class should be used, e.g. `.large { width: 100%; }`; then [`.classList.contains("large")`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to check for its existence, `.classList.toggle("large")`, etc. Consider using the [`<picture>` element](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture), too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that uses some of the suggestions from @SebastianSimon.

1. Event delegation.
2. CSS classes and `classList`.

We attach one listener to the document body, and then check the `nodeName` of the clicked element. If it's an image and the `classList` contains a specific class, replace that class with another. In this case we're replacing "large" with "small".

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick(e) {
  const { nodeName, classList } = e.target;
  if (nodeName === 'IMG') {
    if (classList.contains('large')) {
      classList.replace('large', 'small');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.small { height: 100px; width: 50px; background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/50x100/aa7777'); }
.medium { height: 100px; width: 100px; background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/100x100/77aa77/000'); }
.large { height: 100px; width: 300px; background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/300x100/7777aa/000'); }
```

```html
<img class="medium" />
<img class="large" />
<img class="medium" />
<img class="small" />
<img class="small" />
<img class="large" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.images` will give you an array like `HTMLCollection`

You have to select the image using index to access the image

```
var num = document.images[0].style.width;
```

```js
console.log(document.images);

function iw() {  
  var num = document.images[0].style.width;
  if (num == '300px') {
    alert('Image clicked');
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn-prod.medicalnewstoday.com/content/images/articles/325/325466/man-walking-dog.jpg" style="width:300px;" onclick="iw()">
```

If there are multiple images then you can pass the reference to function and then access the element and do as required

```js
function iw(el) {
    var num = el.style.width;
    if ( num == '300px' ) {
        alert( 'Image clicked' );
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn-prod.medicalnewstoday.com/content/images/articles/325/325466/man-walking-dog.jpg" style="width:300px;" onclick="iw(this)">
    <img src="https://cdn-prod.medicalnewstoday.com/content/images/articles/325/325466/man-walking-dog.jpg" style="width:300px;" onclick="iw(this)">
```

Comment: yes it's work but now I'm facing one another problem.

Comment: You can ask another question on stackoverflow. If you ask here It would be helpful for you but not everyone because there might be many other developers that may face same problems. Hope you understand 

Comment: yeah but still I have to wait for 1day, how about update my queston?

Comment: Sounds good. If there is no option then you have update here

Comment: @decpk Please don’t pity-upvote.

Comment: @Nishant Before asking or updating anything, please try following all the advice you’re given. It sounds like you’re looking for listening for multiple click event targets and adjusting their styles. Use event delegation and the `classList` API.

Comment: Here is my updated question!

Comment: Answer updated. Have a look

Comment: @decpk I want something like this bro: I want to increase size of a single images not all at once. like if user clicked at image first so image first increase if user click at image2 so image 2 incresed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to change size of all the images when one image is clicked, so use the javascript selector function **getElementsByTagName**

```js
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

function enlarge() {

  for(let i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
 
    images[i].width = 200;
  
  }

}
```

```html
<img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/211818.jpg" onclick="enlarge()" width=100>
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/cc/18/8c/cc188c604e58cffd36e1d183c7198d21.jpg" onclick="enlarge()" width=100>
```

run the snippet and try it! if you find any defect please comment, but it worked!

**Edit :-**

you have asked to change the size of only on image, try this, it is simple

```js
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

function enlarge(el) {

    el.width = 200;

}
```

```html
<img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/211818.jpg" onclick="enlarge(this)" width=100>
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/cc/18/8c/cc188c604e58cffd36e1d183c7198d21.jpg" onclick="enlarge(this)" width=100>
```

that's all! if you find any problems again please comment!

Comment: yeah something like this but I want to increase size of a single images not all at once. like if user clicked at image first so image first increase if user click at image2 so image 2 incresed.